# Joomla 1.5 Mootools Dropdown menu free to use plugin

Tags: menu, mootools, drop-down-menu, joomla1.5

Hey I've been looking for this for quite some time now, I know that must be a good Javascript Mootools based free to use (also Commercial use) dropdown menu out there

I just could not find, unlike jQuery that is beyond easy to find a "plugin" that can be ported for Joomla without many problems when it comes to Mootools based plugins compatible with Joomla's code without any core change (or override) it's quite hard

What I want to know is: Is there a good superfish like menu that works on Joomla 1.5?

Keeping in mind that Joomla 1.5 uses an old version of Mootools

Answer (score 0):

You could always use MooMenu -

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/drop-a-tab-menus/9135

However, you should know that Joomla implemented a plugin to allow the use of Mootools 1.2.4. Just make sure you are on the latest version of Joomla and turn on the Mootools Upgrade plugin.